# Creating childs of an abstract class based on childs of another abstract class without knowing their type

Tags: java, class, oop, abstract-class

Consider the following situation:

- I have an abstract class called `Caracteristic` that can have a name and a level. It also overrides `Object.toString()`.
- I have 3 childs of `Caracteristic` called `CaracteristicA`, `CaracteristicB` and `CaracteristicC` that overrides the name (and potentially the level).
- I have an abstract class called `Statistic` that has 2 abstract functions: `int getValue()` and an `Object.toString()` override.
- I have a class called `StatisticA` that extends `Statistic` where overriden `int getValue()`'s result depends on a required `CaracteristicA` and `CaracteristicB` instances. I have a similar class called `StatisticB` but `int getValue()`'s result depends on a required `CaracteristicC` instance. All childs overrides `Statistic.toString()` as well.

---

When I'm creating the statistics for my client, I'm doing something rather ugly which is this:

```
CaracteristicA caracteristicA = null;
CaracteristicB caracteristicB = null;
CaracteristicC caracteristicC = null;

for (Caracteristic currentCaracteristic : listOfCaracteristics) {
    if (currentCaracteristic instanceof CaracteristicA) {
        caracteristicA = (CaracteristicA)currentCaracteristic;
    } if (currentCaracteristic instanceof CaracteristicB) {
        caracteristicB = (CaracteristicB)currentCaracteristic;
    } if (currentCaracteristic instanceof CaracteristicA) {
        caracteristicC = (CaracteristicC)currentCaracteristic;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown caracteristic !");
    }
}

// "client.addStatistic" expects a "Statistic".
// "StatisticA"'s constructor expects an instance of "caracteristicA" and "caracteristicB".
// "StatisticB"'s constructor expects an instance of "caractersiticC".
client.addStatistic(new StatisticA(caracteristicA, caracteristicB));
client.addStatistic(new StatisticB(caracteristicC));
```

**The problem:** if I want to add a `StatisticC` that depends on `CaracteristicA` and a new child of `Caracteristic` (let's call it `CaracteristicD`), I would need to add a variable to store the appropriate caracteristic, add another `else if` in the loop to find it and then I'm finally able to create the needed statistic with the proper caracteristic.

I'm fairly certain that I can simply this whole mess and I would like to know how I could do that. Searching on Google and Stack Overflow seems to point me towards the "**Factory**" and "**Visitor**" design patterns but I'm not sure if they would help me or make it worse.

I also tried adding a `Object getType()` abstract method to `Caracteristic` where childrens would override it with their type (example: `CaracteristicA getType()`) but I realized this would have worked if I knew in advance what child of `listOfCaracteristics` is being iterated.

**UPDATE:** `listOfCaracteristics` is populated by doing `listOfCaracteristics.add(new CaracteristicA());`, `listOfCaracteristics.add(new CaracteristicB());` and so on. Here's the code of the abstract class `Caracteristic`:

```
abstract class Caracteristic {
    private final String name;
    private int level;

    Caracteristique(String name, int level) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return this.level;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And here's the code of one of it's child (`CaracteristicA`):

```
class CaracteristicA extends Caracteristic {
    public CaracteristicA(int level) {
        super("Hello World!", level);
    }

    public CaracteristicA() {
        super("Hello World!", 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `listOfCaracteristics` created and populated ? Can you also show the code of each `Caracteristic` ?

Comment: I updated the question with the requested information. The other `CaracteristicX` childs are identical to the example I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating one instance of each `Caracteristic` and putting them in the list to afterward decompose the list and assign them to variable, just instanciate the variables with the correct `Caracteristic`. This drastically simplifies the code:

```
CaracteristicA caracteristicA = new CaracteristicA();
CaracteristicB caracteristicB = new CaracteristicB();
CaracteristicC caracteristicC = new CaracteristicC();
CaracteristicD caracteristicD = new CaracteristicD(); //hypothetic
client.addStatistic(new StatisticA(caracteristicA, caracteristicB));
client.addStatistic(new StatisticB(caracteristicC));
client.addStatistic(new StatisticC(caracteristicA, caracteristicD)); //hypothetic
```

There is something more that I want to add. The fact that `Caracteristic` is an abstract class but has no member abstract is a sign of a bad design. In the end I suspect the only thing you need is a control over which pair of values (a name and a level) are allowed in `Statistic`.
The whole `Caracteristic` hierarchy could then be simplified with

```
public enum Caracteristic {
    A("Hello World!", 1), B("easy", 2), C("medium", 3), D("hard", 4);

    private final String name;
    private final int level;
    Caracteristic(String name, int level)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public int getLevel() { return level; }
}
```

Which simplify your code again in something like this:

```
client.addStatistic(new StatisticA(Caracteristic.A, Caracteristic.B));
client.addStatistic(new StatisticB(Caracteristic.C));
client.addStatistic(new StatisticC(Caracteristic.A, Caracteristic.D)); //hypothetic
```

Now one have really no benefit to take `Caracteristic` as constructor argument because there exists only one instance of `Caracteristic.A` so they can be directly used inside `StatisticX` !

Again an even more simplified version would become:

```
client.addStatistic(new StatisticA());
client.addStatistic(new StatisticB());
client.addStatistic(new StatisticC()); //hypothetic
```

With, for example, `StatisticA` beeing

```
public final class StatisticA {
    public void DoSomeWork() {
        int differenceLevel = Caracteristic.B.getLevel() - Caracteristic.A.getLevel();
        string bothLevels = Caracteristic.A.toString() + " " + Caracteristic.B.toString();
        System.out.PrintLn(bothLevels + ": " + differenceLevel);
    }
}
```

To make even one more step, I will make the assumption that each `Statistic` does the "same" work (except that it uses different caracteristics). This would allow to refactor into one single class `Statistic`

```
public final class Statistic {
    private final Iterable<Integer> caracs;
    public Statistic(Caracteristic... caracs) {
        this.caracs = Arrays.asList(caracs);
    }
    public void DoSomeWork() {
        System.out.PrintLn(caracs.stream()
                                 .map(Caracteristic::toString)
                                 .Collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
        System.out.PrintLn(caracs.stream()
                                 .map(Caracteristic::getLevel)
                                 .sum());
    }
}
```

With usage becoming (ultimate code simplification)

```
client.addStatistic(new Statistic(Caracteristic.A, Caracteristic.B));
client.addStatistic(new Statistic(Caracteristic.C));
client.addStatistic(new Statistic(Caracteristic.A, Caracteristic.D)); //hypothetic
```

In the beginning one would have:

- 7 classes

With all the simplifications:

- 1 class
- 1 enum

Comment: Assuming I modify my abstract class to now have an abstract method where childs are overriding it, would this still be feasible?

Comment: @Shepard62700FR Absolutely and you can then simplify your code as I described in the first code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong because I'm not very sure to understand the question, but why not use [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to represent the hierarchy of `Carateristic`? 
In this way, you'll be able to create a new `Composite` charateristic (e.g `CaracteristicAB` ) and you can pass it to the `Statistic` that needs more than one `Carateristic`.